# How to get STUN or TURN server on Android app?

Tags: android, webrtc, stun, turn, android-webrtc

Is there a way to get the STUN or TURN server with active connection within an application in **android**, using webRTC, (no javascript). Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the current STUN/TURN which your phone is using?

Comment: Exactly @M.Rostami

Comment: You might not do that because the WebRTC connection is secure (SSL). However, you should explain more about the structure.